# Logback production ready?

Tags: logging, log4j, production, logback

Is [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) production ready? [Latest version(logback-0.9.29.zip)](http://logback.qos.ch/download.html) indicates that it is still < 1.0 . But is it just naming convention ?

Anybody faced issues with it in production ?

We wanted to use it inplaceof Log4j , so your feedback on it will be greatly appreciated, and will be of great help for our team to decide if to go with this decision or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have used Logback for several months now in wide range of products and didn't face any problems so far. If you are really concerned about performance stability, code your application against SLF4J which will allow you to flawlessly switch between Log4J and Logback. Using SLF4J is a actually a must with Logback.

P.S.: It took 15 years to push [Wine](http://www.winehq.org) to 1.0 version.

UPDATE: As of 1st of November 2011 Logback 1.0.0 was [released](http://logback.qos.ch/news.html).